# Unable to cast Async Enumerable Adapter... to Iasync Enumerator IGuildUser

Tags: c#, discord

```
 public async Task ListMembers()
{
IGuildUser[] userVar={};
int usernum;
IAsyncEnumerable<IGuildUser> users = (IAsyncEnumerable<IGuildUser>)Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync();
List<IGuildUser> list = await users.ToListAsync();
list.CopyTo(userVar);
usernum = userVar.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < usernum; i++)
 {
await ReplyAsync(Convert.ToString(userVar[i]));
 }
}
```

I am trying to get all the users in a discord server, and have their names returned when I send a specific command. I get the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'AsyncEnumerableAdapter`1[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[Discord.IGuildUser]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[Discord.IGuildUser]'.
```

Deciphering it is problematic for 2 reasons. One, the error doesn't appear in visual studio, where the actual code is, but rather it appears in a window that pops up when I run the code, and as such, my program doesn't crash, and it doesn't tell me which line it's referring to that has the error. Second, nowhere in my code/the info that is given about the functions and whatnot I am using, does it mention "AsyncEnumerable Adapter", so I can't quite tell what it refers to by that either.

Comment: The error shows in your command line window as your bot setup code probably includes a general error handler which calls a `Console.Write` and passes the error message as a parameter.

Comment: The error looks like it can't convert the type returning from GetUsersAsync to IAsyncEnumerable<IGuildUser>. Not sure off the top of my head what the conversion failure point is, but I think I can see how to simplify the code to that doesn't allow the error to occur.
We should follow the same pattern that `await users.ToListAsync()` is doing. We should rewrite our IGuildUser part to say `var users = await Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync()` to avoid declaring asyncronous crap.

Comment: I just realized I incorrectly formatted what I wrote, 2 different lines of code were written on the same line, so now it is corrected.

Comment: Could you please try re-writing the users line to what I had above and see if that solves the problem. I know it doesn't specifically answer the question, but async code can have interesting errors like this and it's usually better to write cleaner async code first. If the problem still occurs, then let us know and we can move forward from there :).

Comment: I only now just realized you were commenting on both of my posts, thank you for that, it did throw me off as I was just reading the commenter's name. Similar to my last post, I am getting the error `'IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IGuildUser>>' Does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IGuildUser>>' could be found(are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)`
I assume by 'IGuildUser part', you mean the line under 'int usernum;'

Comment: Yes I do mean the part under 'int usernum'

Comment: Yeah, ok that's what I thought. I get that error above, so it seems the "await" is causing a problem, but if I remove the await, more errors pop up in different locations.